# How to second-click by Shift+F10 in Debian?

Tags: debian, keyboard-shortcuts, gnome3, mouse, zenbook

I am having too many artifacts when doing right click (second click) of mouse with the touchpad of UX303UA in Debian 8.5, which is problematic in inspection etc with Mathematica. 
**Goal to fix**: Default <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>f10</kbd> to bring the mouse second click does not work in my hardware (don_crissti)

Characteristics of the system

- Inspecting the keystroke <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>f10</kbd> with `xev`

  ```
  KeyPress event, serial 33, synthetic NO, window 0x2200001,
      root 0x19a, subw 0x0, time 60929622, (375,-9), root:(476,157),
      state 0x0, keycode 50 (keysym 0xffe1, Shift_L), same_screen YES,
      XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
      XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
      XFilterEvent returns: False

  KeyPress event, serial 36, synthetic NO, window 0x2200001,
      root 0x19a, subw 0x0, time 60931790, (375,-9), root:(476,157),
      state 0x1, keycode 121 (keysym 0x1008ff12, XF86AudioMute), same_screen YES,
      XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
      XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
      XFilterEvent returns: False

  KeyRelease event, serial 36, synthetic NO, window 0x2200001,
      root 0x19a, subw 0x0, time 60931880, (375,-9), root:(476,157),
      state 0x1, keycode 121 (keysym 0x1008ff12, XF86AudioMute), same_screen YES,
      XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
      XFilterEvent returns: False
  ```
- *Settings > Mouse & Touchpad* does not have anything relevant about <kbd>fn</kbd> keys.

Fig. 1 Pressing literally <kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd> opens a tab in Google Chrome/Matlab/...; while pressing <kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd> does nothing

[image]

OS: Debian 8.5
Window manager: Gnome 3.14
Hardware: Asus Zenbook UX303UA
Linux kernel: 4.6 of backports
Mathematica: 11

Comment: `Shift+F10` is the standard shortcut in gnome to bring up the context menu.

Comment: I don't get your comment... It does exactly what you request - it emulates a right-click with the mouse which brings up the context menu for the selected item.

Comment: @don_crissti OK, this seems to be a fault in my hardware. Please, see the body.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No supported solution in Gnome 3.14 of Debian 8.5. 
Let's hope the next release of Gnome at Q1-Q2 2017 will target the feature.

Answer (score 1):

If you can't find anything amongst the accessibility features of your desktop environment, you can still bind `xdotool` calls to hotkeys. You'll find some inspiration at http://tuxradar.com/content/xdotool-script-your-mouse.

Comment: I think this one is sufficient `xdotool click 2`. How can you bind it to some key by X/...?

Comment: That depends on your desktop environment or window manager. Try browsing your Settings menu for an appropriate sounding element.

Comment: Try https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Keybindings or https://help.gnome.org/users/gnome-help/stable/keyboard-shortcuts-set.html.en for example. A Google search will give you further read if needed.

Comment: Nothing there about Debian Gnome 3.14 and particularly about the mouse second click.

Comment: No, they're about creating key bindings. You'll have to create a custom key binding for the `xdotool click 3` command.